# SQL Server 2008: Help in optimizing a query using a cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, cursor

I need to rewrite this so it does not cause an overrun on my db. I need to rewrite it so it does not use a cursor.

Thank you.

Comment: Not an answer, but are you sure you need the `DISTINCT`?  That can be very expensive if run against a lot of fields and a lot of rows, and is a likely source of your `tempdb` issues.

Comment: I do not need that it should be commented out, will remove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED** Here's some test data:

```
CREATE TABLE #TableB(SKU INT, BeginYear INT, EndYear INT, OptionA VARCHAR(10), OptionB VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #TableB(SKU, BeginYear, EndYear, OptionA, OptionB)
VALUES  (1, 1920, 1950, 'option1', 'option1'),
        (1, 1980, 2001, 'option1', 'option2'),
        (1, 1940, 1952, 'option1', 'option1'), --overlapping years
        (2, 2001, 2005, 'option1', 'option1')

CREATE TABLE #TableA(SKU INT, OptionA VARCHAR(10), OptionB VARCHAR(10), Years INT)
```

Then you can try a recursive CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT SKU, BeginYear, EndYear, OptionA, OptionB
    FROM #TableB
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SKU, BeginYear+1, EndYear, OptionA, OptionB
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE BeginYear < EndYear
)  
INSERT INTO #TableA(SKU, OptionA, OptionB, Years)
SELECT DISTINCT SKU, OptionA, OptionB, BeginYear
FROM CTE 
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)

SELECT *
FROM #TableA
ORDER BY SKU, OptionA, OptionB, Years
```

Here there's no cartesian product.

Comment: @William - That's weird, it shouldn't do a cartesian effect, can you provide some test data?

Comment: I really don't know why it did, but each record must be distinct and i think that is why i ended up with something like 148M rows before i had a log overrun. SKU, Years, OptionA, OptionB --All rows must be unique as if these four fields were the unique identifer

Comment: @William - The only thing that I see was missing was the `DISTINCT` clause on the first `SELECT` (added that to my answer); other than that, I don't know why it is doing a cartesian product. Are you sure that is that and not just that the EndYears are way way in the future?

Comment: This does however seem to be the correct approach to the problem atleast.  If I could get it to work.

Comment: @Lanak yes, these are all the fields but all fields must act as unique identifier

Comment: @Lanak if i do a COUNT(*) instead of an insert i get the correct number of rows which i am expecting.

Comment: @William - Maybe you have overlapping years on your data. Since you are selecting the distinct values for SKU, OptionA, OptionB, **BeginYear** and **EndYear**. Perhaps you have distinct BeginYears and EndYears for the same SKU, OptionA and OptionB. In this case, you should do a `DISTINCT` at the time you are inserting into your final table. I updated my answer to show that

Answer (score 0):

You can easily substitute a while loop for a cursor and if you are blowing out your tempdb then do some intermediate transactions

---

```
declare @counter int

declare @temptable as tatble (RecID int Identity(1,1),
       SKU Varchar(25),
       OptionA Varchar(50),
       OptionB Varchar(50),
       CurrentYear Int,
       EndYear Int)

insert into @temptable
   Select SKU,OptionA, OptionB, BeginYear,EndYear
   From TableB

set @counter = (select max(recid) from @temptable)

begin transaction

while  @counter <> 0
Begin

    (***whatever sql logic***)

    if (@counter % 5000 = 0) and @@error = 0
        commit Transaction

    begin Transaction

    set @counter = @counter -1
End

commit transaction
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Answer (score -1):

May be use less number of times the insert happen

```
Declare @temp table (
    SKU Varchar(25),
    OptionA Varchar(50),
    OptionB Varchar(50),
    [Year] Int
)

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
    While @CurrentYear <= @EndYear
    Begin
        Insert Into @temp(SKU, OptionA, OptionB, Years)
            Values(@SKU, @OptionA, @OptionB, @CurrentYear)                          

        Set @CurrentYear = @CurrentYear + 1
    End

    Insert Into TableA
        Select * From @temp

    Delete From @temp

    Fetch Next From @Row Into @SKU, @CurrentYear, @EndYear, @OptionA, @OptionB
End
```

Comment: This seems to still use a cursor. Correct?

Comment: Yes, but it is inserting data to the actual table less number of times. The thinking is, that the actual table would have indexes and doing 1 insert of 10 rows would be efficient than doing 10 inserts of 1 row. It still has to be verified if this change actually results in any time saving.

Comment: Can you explain how calling `INSERT INTO Table` for each row in a cursor differs from calling `INSERT INTO Table SELECT * FROM @temp`? It's still performing `n` insert operations on TableA in either case, isn't it..?